# flutter change html image size by using flutter_html libary

Tags: flutter

In my project, my API sends to me HTML String and on it, their image tags

```html
<img src=\"https://static.ghost.org/v3.0.0/images/gallery-sample-1.jpg\" width=\"6000\" height=\"4000\">
```

like this and I want to change the image width and height by using flutter_html library. I mean I want to make custom image size.

Comment: Why would you want to change your image size with an img html tag? If you're working with Flutter you can use Image.network() and use the properties width and height.

Comment: OP is receiving the img info as html and using the library to display it. I have the same question and using flutter Image widget isn't an option.

Comment: Same question - wondering if you ever figured this out?